# My Ionic Modal cannot close

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I have a simple modal form to get comment. When the Submit button or the Close button is clicked, the modal form is supposed to close, but it doesn't.

The following is code snippet from my controller:

```
 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/sharing-comment.html', {
    scope: $scope
 }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.commentForm = modal;
 });

 // Triggered in the comment modal to close it
 $scope.closeCommentForm = function () {
    $scope.commentForm.hide();
 };

 // Open the comment modal
 $scope.showCommentForm = function () {
    $scope.commentForm.show();
    $scope.popover.hide();
 };

 The following is code snippet from my modal form:
 <ion-modal-view>
 <ion-header-bar>
 <h1 class="title">Submit Comment on Sharing</h1>
 <div class="buttons">
   <button class="button button-clear" ng-
 click="closeCommentForm()">Close</button>  
 </div>
 </ion-header-bar>
 <ion-content>
 <form id="commentForm" name="commentForm" ng-submit="submitComment()">
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Your Comment</span>
      <textarea type="text" ng-model="mycomment.comment"></textarea>
    </label>
    <label class="item">
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" 
 type="submit">Submit</button>
    </label>
  </div>
 </form>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-modal-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I made codepen for you

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.commentForm = modal;
  });
  
  $scope.createContact = function() {       
    $scope.commentForm.hide();
  };

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> 
    
    <title>Ionic Modal</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Contacts</h1>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button button-icon ion-compose" ng-click="commentForm.show()">
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <script id="templates/modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-modal-view>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">New Contact</h1>
          <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="commentForm.hide()">Cancel</button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">First Name</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.firstName" type="text">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Last Name</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.lastName" type="text">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <span class="input-label">Email</span>
              <input ng-model="newUser.email" type="text">
            </label>
            <button class="button button-full button-positive" ng-click="createContact(newUser)">Create</button>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```